# django multi file upload fields

Tags: django, django-models, file-upload

- List item
- registration start date
- Year
- Vin#
- Make
- Title Owner (Upload field) ==== (can be several files)
- HUT # (Upload field) ==== (can be several files)
- Ifta # (Upload field) ==== (can be several files)

**I need that model**

If file upload fields had to be for a single file, then it would be okay, but how Can I handle that model?

*(Should I create ForeignKey models for every file_upload field in order to handle multi file uploads??)*

Answer (score 0):

I would write something like this:

```
files_titleowner = models.ManyToManyField(FileTitleOwner, related_name="mymodel_filetitleowner", blank=True)
...
```

and so on. I usually specify the related_name attribute for each many to many field.

FileTitleOwner could be like this:

```
class FileTitleOwner(models.Model):
   file = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path,
                        null=True, blank=True,
                        verbose_name="...")
   ...
```

Also, user_directory_path is a function which returns the pathname for the file to be stored on file system:

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
   ...
   return f"{<construct opportunely a directory name>}/{filename}"
```